# Integrating post archive wtih another source and preserving date ordering

Tags: query-posts

I'm pulling posts from Instagram into the WP basic archive view; but I want things to display in order of date, and not screw up paging (too much). The outcome should look like this:

**BLOG POST JUNE 4th**

*INSTAGRAM IMAGE JUNE 3rd*

*INSTAGAM IMAGE JUNE 2nd*

**BLOG POST JUNE 1st**

**BLOG POST MAY 20**

ETC

Is there any easy way to do something like this, other than reading the `$wp_query` global variable and then pulling only instagrams from that? Something like pulling posts into array and using ksort? Any advice would be appreciated.

UPDATE:

The Instagram feed is integrated via CURL (and an authorized Instagram dev app) and displayed on the page, NOT stored in the WP DB. I realize I could store them but I'm integrating a high-traffic account and don't want to create 100x of posts uselessly (not to mention, why replicate Instagram's existing API?).

**SOLUTION**:

I used a combination inspired by both the answers below; I ended up getting the "maximum" and "minimum" dates from the posts in the `$wp_query` object (eg the latest and first) and pulling from between those via the instagram endpoint; I then gathered those into one array, `krsort`'d it and then relooped and printed out. Thanks all!

Comment: The instagram posts are not in the WordPress database at all, in any way?

Comment: How are you getting this other feed? What does your code look like so far?

Comment: updated post to answer these questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without knowing more about what your Instagram data feed object looks like, I would do something like this, assuming you already have a `$wp_query` object with *real* posts in it.

```
// we're going to merge both objects into one array so we can sort it
$merge_array = array();

// run through actual posts, assuming you already have a wp_query object built
while($loop->have_posts()): $loop->the_post();
    $merge_array[] = array(
        // store original post ID for later reference
        'post_id' => $post->ID,
        'date' => date('U', strtotime($post->post_date)),
    );
endwhile;

// now loop through instagram stuff and fill up merge array with it as well
foreach($mysterious_instgram_ojbect as $instagram_image){
    $merge_array[] = array(
        'post_id' => false, // set this false to know it is not WP post object
        'date' => date('U', $instagram_image->date), // guessing here
        // store more info here such as image URL and/or title
    );
}
```

Now we've stuffed the important bits into one array. Let's sort them!

```
// sort them by date, function defined below
$merge_array_sorted = array_msort($merge_array, array('date' => SORT_DESC));
```

And loop them for final output.

```
foreach($merge_array_sorted as $feed_object){
    echo date('F js', $feed_object['date']);
    if($feed_object['post_id']){
        // is post, treat as wordpress post!
        echo get_the_title($feed_object['post_id']);
        echo get_permalink($feed_object['post_id']);
    } else {
        // is instagram, treat accordingly
    }
}
```

Put this in your functions. It's a pretty great multidimensional array sorter, referenced above.

```
// world famous multidimensional array sort function
function array_msort($array, $cols) {
    $colarr = array();
    foreach ($cols as $col => $order) {
        $colarr[$col] = array();
        foreach ($array as $k => $row) { $colarr[$col]['_'.$k] = strtolower($row[$col]); }
    }
    $eval = 'array_multisort(';
    foreach ($cols as $col => $order) {
        $eval .= '$colarr[\''.$col.'\'],'.$order.',';
    }
    $eval = substr($eval,0,-1).');';
    eval($eval);
    $ret = array();
    foreach ($colarr as $col => $arr) {
        foreach ($arr as $k => $v) {
            $k = substr($k,1);
            if (!isset($ret[$k])) $ret[$k] = $array[$k];
            $ret[$k][$col] = $array[$k][$col];
        }
    }
    return $ret;
}
```

This is a loose example. The objects should now be sorted by a Unix time stamp, which you can convert back to a more usable date. You can easily reference WP functions like `the_content()` and dress it all up in your last `foreach` loop. Let me know if this needs further explanation.

Comment: Love this answer and am close to having it setup, but trying to figure out why I'm getting this error: "PHP Warning:  array_multisort(): Argument #2 is expected to be an array or a sort flag in /Users/jakelisby/Sites/dewsly.lc/wp-content/themes/dewslyWeb/functions.php(1572) : eval()'d code on line 1"

Comment: Ooops. That's because I was missing a line. Updated. Need flag for direction. can use SORT_ASC or SORT_DESC

Comment: BOOM! This is perfect, I'm up and running now. When I add in s_ha_dum's answer for the date ranges this will be just delightful. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

If both your Instagram posts and your WordPress Posts are ordered by date descending you should be able to do something like this:

```
if (have_posts()) {
  while (have_posts()) {
    the_post();
    the_content(); // etc.
    while ($instagram_date > $post->post_date && $instagram_date < $posts[$wp_query->current_post +1]) {
      // insert instagram posts
    }
  }
}
```

Your `posts_per_page` will be off, as the only thing included in that calculation would be WordPress posts, but pagination should still work.

Obviously that is very rough code-- practically pseudo-code. I don't know how your Instagram posts come in-- array, object-- or what they look like. You will need to work out retrieving the Instagram date and advancing the pointer for the Instagram array/object/whatever-it-is. I assume you'd need an iterator for that array/object or use `array_shift` perhaps.

Checking the `$post->post_date` and comparing it to `$posts[$wp_query->current_post +1]` should be the key to inserting by date though. I think that is the most minimal memory/processing approach.